# How to maintain consistent sizing and alignment in a Vue.js component (navbar-list-item) when used inside a router-link?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a list item component:

```
<template>
  <div
    @click="customEvent"
    class="text-md my-3 flex h-fit w-fit cursor-pointer flex-nowrap items-center gap-5 whitespace-nowrap py-3 pl-5 pr-4 font-semibold drop-shadow-md transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105"
  >
    <div name="box" class="h-[30px] w-[5px] rounded-xl bg-black"></div>
    <div>
      <Icon :icon="icon" width="30" height="30" />
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and it is used in Navbar as routerlink

```
 <ul v-for="item in NavbarListItems" :key="item.name" @click="item.fun">
      <li>
        <router-link
          exact-active-class="text-teal-500"
          :to="`/HelloUser/${item.component}`"
          exact
          class="flex"
        >
          <navbar-list-item class="grow h-[100%] w-[100%]" :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name"></navbar-list-item
        ></router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

inside the router-link theres a navbar-list-item which has a diffrent size for no reason.

[image]

How to fix it and align or control the inner tag?